# Scala date time convertion using joda datetime

Tags: scala, datetime, jodatime

I have try to convert date time to yyyy/MM/dd format using joda. but I got this error.

> Invalid format: "2016-03-10T15:45:03.000+05:30" is malformed at
>   "T15:45:03.000+05:30" : ()

here is my method

```
val dateFormatGeneration: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
            def convertDateTime(dt:DateTime):String={
                dateFormatGeneration.parseDateTime(dt.toString).toString
            }
```

simply i need to convert joda  datetime object to string as `yyyy/MM/dd` format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the easiest would be to just use `DateTimeFormatter`'s [`print()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#print(org.joda.time.ReadableInstant)) method:

```
val dateFormatGeneration: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

def convertDateTime(dt:DateTime):String={
    dateFormatGeneration.print(dt)
}
```